# p:inplace doesn't call setter

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am attempting to utilize the `<p:inplace>` functionality with a `<p:inputTextarea>`.  It "works", but the data from the inputTextarea is never 'saved'.  'Saved' meaning that the setter of the property behind the inputTextarea is never called.  The getter is called before and after the save button is clicked.  I've seen posts about the `<p:ajax>` usage for `<p:inplace>`, however that appears to be an event AFTER the setter was supposed to be called.  What am I doing wrong??

```
<p:inplace editor="true" emptyLabel="No comments entered.">
    <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{bean.handleSave}"
            update="commentsSuperPanel"/>
    <p:inputTextarea
            id="commentsOverall"
            value="#{bean.comments}"
            styleClass="commentAreas" 
            maxlength="4000"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Discovered that there was an unrelated issue presenting itself without warning or error.  I had a dialog that contained a form; and that dialog was defined inside another form.  I moved the dialog declaration outside of the form, and all worked as expected.